# Toggle button only works on first article

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I have a toggle button who hide/shows, and appears on every article. (My site have around a million articles)

But on each site it the toggle button only toggles the first/top article.

HTML:

```
<button class="proddetBtn" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="myFunction()"><div>Show productdetails</div>
     </button>

<div id="myCRITERIA" style="display: ">
  <?php echo $criteria ?>
</div> <br>
```

Js:

```
 function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById('myCRITERIA');
     if (x.style.display === 'none') {
         x.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
         x.style.display = 'none';
     }
 }
```

Comment: fill the criteria div with sample data

Comment: `document.getElementById('myCRITERIA');` selects only element, pass ID attribute dynamically...

Comment: how do I pass ID attribute? sorry, I'm an amateur

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with OP's code. I made [a Pen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/awWPoB) out of it and it works.

Comment: The code works, but only for the first element. It creates a button on each article, but when I press the buttons it only hides/shows the text on the first article.

Comment: Ah right, that's because an ID must be unique across the whole document. As @Prasad said, you have to pass the target's ID to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `targeted element Id` with in a function .Then applying the toggle effect with ternary operator

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
x.style.display = x.style.display === 'none'? 'block' :'none';
}
```

```html
<button class="proddetBtn" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="myFunction('myCRITERIA')"><div>Show productdetails</div>
 </button>

<div id="myCRITERIA" style="display: ">
some
  <?php echo $criteria ?>
</div> <br>
```

**Updated**

Or more number of element you can use with in class.`ForEach` used for  iterate the elements

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.clear').forEach(function(a) {
    a.style.display = a.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="proddetBtn" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="myFunction()"><div>Show productdetails</div>
 </button>

<div class="clear" style="display:none">some</div> <br>
<div  class="clear" style="display:none ">some</div> <br>
<div  class="clear" style="display: ">some</div> <br>
<div  class="clear" style="display:none ">some</div> <br>
<div class="clear" style="display: ">some</div> <br>
<div  class="clear" style="display:none ">some</div> <br>
<div  class="clear" style="display: ">some</div> <br>
```

Comment: The first code gave me the same issue as the original code. It only toggles the first element. The second code gave me four lines saying 'some' which were there constantly, and only toggled some white space at the top.

Comment: The second code is on the right track I think. It toggles on each article, but all of them at the same time. So when I click one of them it affects all e.g 50 articles on the page.

Comment: yes you are right.Clicked element and hiding element is different

Comment: @Prasad, you have 8 times `id="myCRITERIA"`, yurgh, please remove that before I downvote too :)

Comment: I replaced all of the 'some' elements with a <?php echo $criteria ?> ($criteria outputs the unique productdetails per article), and it kind of works. It hides/shows on all of the elements at the same time, but it's better than what it was :) Thanks